# Are there any other materials on Hamilton-Jacobi equation besides the book by Evans?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I've been recently reading the book on PDE by Evans,and I had a hard time understanding the part about Hamilton-Jacobi equation in chapter 3.I wonder if there are any other materials on this subject,which can help me capture some intuition on Legendre transform and the derivation of Hopf-Lax formula.Thank you!!

Comment: Could you please give a link to the Evans book ?. Thanks.

Comment: I already found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For intuition about Legendre transform as well as for Hamilton Jacobi equation, I would recommend *Classical Mechanics* by H.Goldstein.